# Unable to get $rootscope object on pageload in angularjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I am using ng-token-auth and devise token-auth.

When the user gets logged in it stores user.id in $rootScope

this is my controller

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($rootScope,MyFactory){
     console.log($rootScope);
     console.log($rootScope.user.id);
})
```

The output for first is:

Object {$id: 1, $$childTail: Object, $$childHead: Object, $$prevSibling: null, $$nextSibling: null…}
The Output for 2nd is:
undefined

But when we expand the first Output it contains user.id
user: Object
configName: "default"
email: "abc@gmail.com"
id: 3
provider: "email"
signedIn: true
status: null
uid: "17d851ed-4"
**proto**: Object

Comment: Where is the code where you store the user data in the controller? Seems like you are just assigning it wrong.

Comment: Devise gem is assigning user attributes to rootscope. i dont know how it is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason for that might be that you're trying to access a property, that is not YET assigned (maybe a promise is being resolved or something?).

to make sure, just add a `debugger` statement in your controller and then see if the actual `user` property at that given moment.

---

to defer the action that would use that `user.id`, try following:

```
app.controller( 'MyCtrl', function( $rootScope, MyFactory ) {
  var unwatch = $rootScope.$watch( 'user.id', function ( id ) {
    if ( angular.isDefined( id ) {
      // use the ID, as it seems to be defined now
      console.log( id );

      // remove the watch, because there's no more use for it
      unwatch();
    }
  });
});
```

---

to create a better, reusable functionality, you can create a small service that would return a promise, like so:

```
app.service( 'getUserID', function( $rootScope, $q ) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  var unwatch = $rootScope.$watch( 'user.id', function ( id ) {
    if ( angular.isDefined( id ) {
      // resolve the promise, as it seems to be defined now
      deferred.resolve( id );

      // remove the watch, because there's no more use for it
      unwatch();
    }
  });

  return function () {
    return deferred.promise;
  }
});

// let's use it:
app.controller( 'MyCtrl', function( getUserID ) {
  // value returned from this service is a promise that will be resolved with user.id
  getUserID().then( function ( id ) {
    // use the id
  });
});
```

Comment: i am getting the value of user.id i the markup like this       
<a href="#">{{user.id}}</a> but not in controller

Comment: my guess is that it's being updated at later stage. try adding this statement in your controller: `console.log(angular.copy($rootScope.user));`

Comment: It give empty object Object{}

Comment: so that means that the `$rootScope.user` is updated at later stage. why do you need to have it in your controller? maybe defer what you're doing until the `id` is there?

Comment: i want to fetch data  that belongs to that user.id in the controller.Can you give me some example how can i defer

Comment: Is it a good practice to use $watch in each controller. because we need to get data inside every controller based in user.id ?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you must be populating user at a later time. What chrome is showing in the console is correct because it has the object reference for $rootScope. So you're looking at it not when it was console logged but what it is right now.

Answer (score 0):

while assigning the user id to rootscope, follow the below steps

$rootScope.user = {};
$rootScope.user.id = test;